# Glorious Crashing while copying lists

Tags: c++

So I'm about ready to toss my computer out of a window, and I'm now at the point where I figure I should ask for help before I destroy an expensive piece of equipment.

My program has a list that is filled in automatically (I manually input the items), and it just outputs it. Then, I have another block of code that is to output it again using assignment operators, and then a third copy with a copy constructor.

The assignment operator crashes the program, but if I comment it out to let it get to the copy constructor, the list comes out empty.

Anything that says "TODO" you can ignore, that's noted for me to fix later.

Here is where all the action happens:

## List.cpp

(This is not my main function, there's nothing wrong there)

```
    List::List() : m_pFront(0), m_pBack(0), _pData(0)
    {}

    List::~List()
    {
        Clear();
    }    

    List::List(const char* p)
    {
        if(!p)
        {
            _pData = 0;
            return;
        }
        if(strlen(p) == 0)
        {
            _pData = 0;
            return;
        }
        _pData = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
        strcpy(_pData, p);
    }

    void List::Clear()
    {
        //delete 
        if(!m_pFront)
        {
            return;
        }
        delete m_pFront;
        Node* p = m_pBack;
        //Walking the list
        while(p)
        {
            //Get a pointer to the next in the list
            Node* pTemp = p -> m_pNext;
            delete p;
            //Move p along the list
            p = pTemp;
        }
        m_pFront = 0;
        m_pBack = 0;
    }

    void List::PushFront(std::string data)
    {
        //create a new node
        Node* p = new Node(data);

        //Empty list    
        if(!m_pFront)
        {
            m_pFront = p;
            m_pBack = p;
        }
        else //Not empty list
        {
            p -> m_pNext = m_pFront;
            m_pFront -> m_pPrev = p;
            m_pFront = p;
        }
    }

    void List::PushBack(std::string data)
    {
        Node* p =  new Node(data);

        if(!m_pBack)
        {
            m_pFront = p;
            m_pBack = p;        
        }
        else
        {
            p -> m_pPrev = m_pBack;
            m_pBack -> m_pNext = p;
            m_pBack = p;
        }       
    }    

    void List::PopFront()
    {
        if(m_pFront == 0)
        {
            //TODO: we need to handle this problem
            return;
        }
        if(m_pBack == m_pFront)
        {
            Clear();
            return;
        }
        Node* p = m_pFront;
        m_pFront = m_pFront -> m_pNext;
        p -> m_pNext = 0;
        m_pFront -> m_pPrev = 0;    
        delete p;
    }

    void List::PopBack()
    {
        if(m_pBack == 0)
        {
            //TODO: we need to handle this problem
            return;
        }
        if(m_pBack == m_pFront)
        {
            Clear();
            return;
        }
        Node* p = m_pBack;
        m_pBack = m_pBack -> m_pPrev;
        p -> m_pPrev = 0;
        m_pBack -> m_pNext = 0;
        delete p;
    }


    ostream& List::OutPut(ostream& os)
    {
        if(Empty() == true)
        {
            os << "<empty>";
        }
        else
        {
            m_pFront -> OutputNode(os);
        }
        return os;    
    }    


    std::string& List::Back() const
    {
        if(m_pBack == 0)
        {
            //TODO: we need to handle this problem
        }
        return m_pBack -> GetData();
    }

    std::string& List::Front() const
    {
        if(m_pFront == 0)
        {
            //TODO: we need to handle this problem
        }
    return m_pFront -> GetData();  
    }

    //Copy Constructor
    List::List(const List& str)
    {
        if(Empty() == true)
        {
            _pData = 0;
            return;
        }
        _pData = new char[strlen(str._pData) + 1];
        strcpy(_pData, str._pData);
    }
    //Deep copy
    List& List::operator=(const List& str)
    {
        if(&str == this)
        {
            return *this;
        }
        delete [] _pData;
        _pData = new char[strlen(str._pData) + 1];
        strcpy(_pData, str._pData);
        return *this;
    }
```

**EDIT:** This is where the List class is made, if this needs to be seen as well

## List.h

```
class List
{
    public:
        List();
        List(const char* p);
        //Copy constructor
        List(const List& str);
        //Deep Copy
        List& operator=(const List& str);
        ~List();
        void Clear();
        //Adds to the front 
        void PushFront(std::string data);
        //adds to the back
        void PushBack(std::string data);
        //removes from the front
        void PopFront();
        //removes from the back
        void PopBack();
        //gets the back value
        std::string& Back() const;
        //gets the from value
        std::string& Front() const;

        bool Empty() const {return m_pFront == 0;}

        ostream& OutPut(ostream& os);

    private:    
        Node* m_pFront;
        Node* m_pBack;
        char* _pData;

    };
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm doing this from a visual studio command prompt. This is a side project for myself in class, and we will actually start using Visual Studio tomorrow. I'm using Notepad++ to actually do the coding.

Comment: What does that have to do with debugging it?

Comment: How would I go about debugging it if using Visual Studio is irrelevant? I've only been in C++ for about a month, and debugging isn't something we've had to do yet.

Comment: I don't know anything about visual studio, sorry.  Doesn't it have a debugger?

Comment: @CarlNorum: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: Alas, I am using Windows and not Unix.

Comment: Even without a dedicated debugging utility, there's always good 'ole fashioned `printf` debugging. You can use them (various methods that output to stdout/stderr) to try to figure out how far the code gets before it explodes into flames. That won't always tell you WHY it crashed, but it should give you some good hints.

Comment: Unfortunately I know exactly where it crashes, its when the list is copied using the assignment operator and no other time, which it does actually say in my main post.

Comment: Where in the assignment operator, though? What's the state of various variables (and the addresses of any pointers)? Is it what you'd expect?

Comment: The point at which is crashes is `_pData = new char[strlen(str._pData) + 1];` Another problem is that when I comment out the call to the assignment operator in the main function, which then allows it to move on to the copy constructor, the list it is supposed to display actually comes out empty.

Comment: Try printing out `str._pData` right before that line and see if what you expect gets spit out. It sounds like the passed in `str` is likely in some sort of bad state already, as that code itself seems okay.

Comment: I threw in two debugging statements directly before like you said, and it crashed immediately following the first statement, when trying to access `str._pData` itself.

Comment: Many issues: your copy constructor never initializes `m_pFront` or `m_pBack` but it immediately invokes `Empty` which checks `m_pFront` – I suspect you wanted `str.Empty()` instead (this, by the way, cause cause you to call `strlen` with a null pointer which will crash). Your assignment operator doesn't copy or set `m_pFront` or `m_pBack` either and those may continue to be uninitialized when used and then what? Your `List::List(const char *)` doesn't initialize `m_pFront` or `m_pBack` either. Fix those things first, and then if your program is still crashing, we can take a closer look.

Comment: Is there a reason why `_pData` is a `char *` instead of an `std::string`?

Comment: @AndrewB I suggest also checking out **[Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)**. That method works quite well here since you can catch any coding errors the moment you introduce it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's what's happening:

In your copy constructor, you check whether the list is empty. The result of this check is undefined because `m_pFront` is uninitialized, but in a debug build, chances are that this check is always true. Either way, since you're not actually copying any nodes, but only `_pData`, the resulting list will be empty (with the exception of `_pData` maybe being set).

In your assignment operator, before the line `_pData = new char[strlen(str._pData) + 1];` you fail to check if `str._pData` actually points to anything. If it doesn't and you're essentially doing `strlen(0)`, that is where it crashes and burns.

My advice would be to get a proper implementation of your copy constructor. One that actually does a deep copy, and then implement the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/2700399) for your assignment operator.

**EDIT: Example**

The source code below implements a small subset of the list class from the question to demonstrate a deep copy constructor and an assignment operator using the copy and swap idiom mentioned in the paragraph above.

Before I show the source code, it is important to realize that deep copying a list is not easy. A number of things have to be considered. You have to make copies of the nodes. You probably want to make copies of the data. But maybe not deep copies. Or maybe your specific needs don't require a copy of the data at all.

In your case, the list is doubly linked. If `Node` had a copy constructor that does a naive deep copy you would probably end up with a stack overflow due to endless chaining of the copy constructor.

Here's an example of such a naive implementation.

```
Node(const Node &other) 
{
    if (other.next) 
        next = new Node(*other.next);
    if (other.prev) 
        prev = new Node(*other.prev);
}
```

In my example, I choose to not implement a copy constructor for Node for clarity. I choose to make copies of the data, which is in the form of `std::string` to match the question.

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_EXAMPLE_H_
#define LIST_EXAMPLE_H_

#include <string>

struct Node
{
    std::string data;
    Node *next, *prev;
    Node(const std::string &d) 
        : next(0), prev(0), data(d)
    {
    }
};

class List
{
    Node *front;
    Node *back;
    std::string data;

public:
    List();
    List(const std::string &);
    List(const List &);
    ~List();

    List& operator=(List);

    void Clear();
    void PushBack(const std::string&);

    bool Empty() const { return front == 0; }

    friend void swap(List &, List &);

    void Print();
};

#endif // LIST_EXAMPLE_H_
```

**list.cc**

```
#include "list.h"
#include <iostream>

List::List()
    : front(0), back(0), data()
{
}

List::List(const std::string &in)
    : front(0), back(0), data(in)
{
}

List::~List()
{
    Clear();
}

List::List(const List &other)
    : front(0), back(0), data(other.data)
{
    if (!other.Empty())
        for (Node *node = other.front; node; node = node->next) 
            PushBack(node->data);
}

List& List::operator=(List other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}

void List::Clear()
{
    Node *node = front;
    while (node) {
        Node *to_delete = node;
        node = node->next;
        delete to_delete;
    }
    front = back = 0;
}

void List::PushBack(const std::string &data)
{
    Node *node = new Node(data);
    if (Empty()) {
        front = back = node;
    } else {
        back->next = node;
        node->prev = back;
        back = node;
    }
}

void List::Print()
{
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    for (Node *node = front; node; node = node->next)
        std::cout << node->data << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void swap(List &first, List &second)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(first.front, second.front);
    swap(first.back, second.back);
    swap(first.data, second.data);
}

int main()
{
    List a("foo");
    a.PushBack("a");
    a.PushBack("b");
    a.PushBack("c");
    a.Print();

    List b("bar");
    b.PushBack("d");
    b.PushBack("e");
    b.PushBack("f");

    List c(b);
    c.Print();

    c = a;
    c.Print();
    a.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Why the assignment operator and the swap function are the way they are is explained much better than I can in the aforementioned answer that describes the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/2700399). That leaves us with the implementation of the copy constructor. Let's look at it line by line.

```
1. List::List(const List &other)
2.     : front(0), back(0), data(other.data)
3. {
4.     if (!other.Empty())
5.         for (Node *node = other.front; node; node = node->next) 
6.             PushBack(node->data);
7. }
```

1. Our copy constructor takes a reference to a const list. We promise not to change it.
2. We initialize our own members. Since `data` is not a pointer we might as well copy it in the initializer.
3. Yeah, I have to add this line for proper markdown numbering.
4. If the other list is empty, we're done here. There is no reason to check whether the list we just constructed is empty. It obviously is.
5. For each node in the other list... (sorry, markdown syntax again, doesn't let me combine 5 and 6 nicely).
6. ...we create a new one. As explained above, there's no copy constructor for `Node` in this example, so we just use our `PushBack` method.
7. For completeness sake, but this line is totally obvious.

Looping over the nodes in the other list this way is not the nicest. You should prefer using an iterator and calling `PushBack(*iter)`.

Comment: After numerous attempts at trying to properly implement my copy constructor, I'm coming up blank. Do you have any tips? I've only gone through a month of an accelerated C++ course so I'm having trouble grasping some concepts, and this is just one of them.

Comment: @AndrewB If you add what you've tried, then I (and others) can give you feedback. After I come off work today I'll update my answer with an explained working example, as well as feedback on updates you may have.